# Why local variables are not accessible from other functions?

Tags: c#, memory

I'm currently learning about computer memory and asking questions to myself to understand it better.

I learned about how a new space is allocated in the stack whenever a function is called.
**But why we can't reach local variables even though they are still on the stack? What is it that prevents me from accessing them while they are still on the stack?**

Consider the following code (Please look at the comments):

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int number = 5; 

        Method();

    } //<------ number variable will be stored in the stack until the program reaches here.

    public static void Method()
    {

        // number=5 variable is still on the stack so why can't I reach it here?

        number = 10; // throws an error because it's not defined in this scope but it's still on the stack.

        int anotherNumber = 2; 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to access `number` then pass it to the `Method` by reference: `void Method(ref int outerNumber)`

Comment: @PeterCsala I know, but I'm trying to understand the logic behind it. Why it's not possible to reach it without passing a parameter while the number is still in the stack?

Comment: "on the stack" and "in scope" are two entirely different things. Imagine you have a third method, and inside it you didn't declare the `int number`, so there is no number on the stack but still decided to call `Method`, if this were legal C# code your program would compile and then run into undefined behaivour because there is no number on the stack. Methods cannot (and should not) make assumptions about the state of the stack.

Comment: Like most modern languages, C# uses static scoping. Some older languages use dynamic scoping, in which a function can access any variable from any caller. Dynamic scoping makes it harder to reason about how a function works. For example, if C# had dynamic scoping, you couldn't tell by reading `Method` .what type `number` is. Is it an integer? A string? Or maybe it doesn't exist at all. It also makes it hard to reason about `Main`: Any variable could change at any function call!

Comment: If you would define the `Method` as a local method or as an anonymous function then you could access it due to closure.

Comment: What if you called `Method()`from somewhere else (not from `Main`) what should it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C and languages derived from it, functions are separately compiled so they cannot "see" the local variables of each other. This is a design decision.

In Pascal and languages derived from it, this is made possible by allowing nested function declarations. A function declared inside another sees the local variables of the latter as global ones.

---

But beware that via mutual and recursive calls, the same variable can exist at several places in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

If that code could compile (i.e. if you comment out `number = 10;`), the variable number would likely not even be on the stack in a Release build because it's unused and the optimizer would realize that.

C# uses scoping for variables, and the scope of the variable `number` is the `Main()` method. If you define it inside the class instead, it'd be a class member and would be accessible also from the method `Method()`. As a general rule of thumb, though, always try to limit the scope of variables.

```
class Program
{
    static int number = 5; // class member

    public static void Main()
    {
        Method();    
    }

    public static void Method()
    {    
        number = 10; // no error anymore

        int anotherNumber = 2; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The "optimized away" argument does not hold. If there was a mechanism allowing a function to access other functions' local variables, this would be somehow resolved.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I'm not so sure. The ECMA specification (ECMA 334 Section 10.9) […] states:

“For instance, if a local variable that is in scope is the only existing reference to an object, but that local variable is never referred to in any possible continuation of execution from the current execution point in the procedure, an implementation might (but is not required to) treat the object as no longer in use.”

Comment: This doesn't compile. Did you mean to define number as `static int number = 5;`

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti: you don't understand. If there was a mechanism blah blah, the ECMA specification would be different.

Answer (score -1):

> variable is still on the stack so why can't I reach it here?

This argument hold as much water as "all variables are in memory so why can't I access  from everywhere all variables, including variables from other programs, after all they are all on the same memory right?"

There are so many problems with what you propose. From encapsulation, to name pollution, to optimization, to security.

A local variable is just that: a local variable. It's for me, it's an **implementation detail**. The outside world should not know about it because since it's mine and I use it for my internal purposes I can change it or remove it at my will. With your proposal what? Now I can't change **my own local variable** because some function somewhere down the calling chain uses it. And why does it uses it? If I want to pass some information to the function I call then that should be done via parameters.

```
void foo() { int mine;  bar(); }
void bar() { void baz(); }
void baz() { mine = 24; } // like wtf??
```

Besides how would you handle this situation:

```
void foo_1()
{
    int mine; // I can name it mine because it's a local variable
    bar();
}

void foo_2()
{
    int mine; // I can also name it mine because it's a local variable
    bar();
}

void foo_3()
{
    bar();
}

void bar()
{
    mine = 24; // ??????
}
```

In concussion to pass information from one function to another we use parameters, we don't pollute a fictional "global local namespace" because we are not savages.

Comment: I understand why it's necessary but i was trying to understand why it was happening. So programming language prevents me to access it somehow?

Comment: Of course. Any programming language has its set of rules.